# Запрос к базе с чужего сайта на прямую

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток

Есть подключение к бд, ест-но выполняются определенные запросы. А можно ли со стороннего сайта (и как если можно) производить запросы select/insert/update/delete к определенному сайту

p.s. Если как то не корректно спросил, прошу указать, что не так, т.к. спросил про то, что не совсем понимаю. Собственно хочется С одного сайта копаться в бд другого

Comment: @frank вы имеете ввиду запросы в БД? База данных может находится в любом месте.

Comment: по-моему навикат и аналоги поддерживаю подключение к удалённому хосту

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, для этого необходимо, чтобы БД "слушала" подключения извне и у пользователя, которым подключаемся были права не подлючение и выпонение какихлибо действий.

Comment: я был бы раз простому примеру (допустим права есть)

Comment: примеру чего? :) запрос ничем не будет оличаться кроме имени хоста, к которому подключаемся. а так все совершенно тоже самое.  
если про настройку mysql, то это уже не сюда, а на руткод) а лучше в документацию по mysql

Answer (score 1):

Через так называемый HTTP туннель. Для этого на сайт загружается скрипт, который вызывается извне через HTTP. Можете глянуть [сюда](http://www.mysqlfront.de/) и скачать программу. В ее комплекте есть файл для организации туннеля - **libMySQL.php**. Через меню настроек сессий сможете подключиться, указав полный путь до файла в настройках сессии, но предварительно загрузив этот файл на удаленный сервер. Если речь идет об управлении не через программу, а через скрипт с другого сайта, то можете обычным протокол-анализатором посмотреть, как она работает через HTTP со своим **libMySQL.php** и воплотить у себя в своем скрипте аналогичные вызовы.

Comment: Тоже вариант. Только искал вообще прямой метод.

Comment: какой прямой??? mysql_connect(host..,)?